# How to easily convert a comma seperated list of ids into a table of rows

Tags: postgresql

I want to compare a comma-separated list of IDs to the result of a query, something like this:

```
select * from  (values (2201322723),
(2201318904),
(2201299380),
(2164969641),
(5682476934),
(2201314720),
) as t(object_id)
EXCEPT
select object_id from star.dim_partner where entity = 'partners' and is_active is true;
```

The above works, however, it required me to use a text editor with column based support to add round brackets (the list was actually quite a bit longer).

Is there and easier/better way to convert a comma separated list into a (temp) table with PostgreSQL?

a bit like:

```
select item as object_id from ARRAY[6058271246, 2201299240, 1801904030, 2097401903];
```

?

This will them allow me to cut-and-paste any list of IDs in between the square brackets.

Comment: One of the numerous JSON functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `string_to_array()` together with `unnest()`

```
select * 
from unnest(string_to_array('2201322723,2201318904,2201299380,2164969641', ',')) as t(object_id)
```

Or if you are using Postgres 14 or later this can be simplified to

```
select * 
from string_to_table('2201322723,2201318904,2201299380,2164969641', ',') as t(object_id)
```